# Google Visualization API - Error: Unknown header type: 1

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

When I try to load my site on my WAMP-Server, it gives me this error:

```
Error: Unknown header type: 1
https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/c3581c99759b4a64cb69ca21ab634266/format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js
Line 171
```

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>SO Q#</title>
<style type="text/css">
html {
    height: 100%; 
    width:  100%
}
body {
    height:  100%; 
    width:   100%; 
    margin:  0; 
    padding: 0
}
#chart { 
    height: 100%; 
    width:  100% 
}
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../js/jquery.csv.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    $.get("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ao6fMN9Cw0GPdFVtZ29iYmd1cmRORU0yemYxUjE3OVE&single=true&gid=0&output=csv",    function(csvString) {
    var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0,1]);
        var options = {
            title: "A Chart from a CSV!",
            legend: 'none'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
        chart.draw(view, options);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me where this error comes from?

Comment: Try to open https link from `$.get()` call in your browser. You have to get `testchart.csv` file from that google site.

Comment: I got the file. Now I changed the code to: "$.get("testchart.csv",    function(csvString) {",  is this right?

Comment: Yes, if that file is in the same directory as your html file.

Comment: It is, but the error is the same :/

Comment: Yes, arrayToDataTable(arrayData) fails.

Comment: And is there a reason why it fails? Or any way to make it not to fail any more? I´m sorry for stealing your time, but I´m new to the google visualization api :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Header of that file is not proper for pieChart. Change it to something like

```
Name,Work
Jochen,2
Peter,5
Hans,2
Detlef,3
Jürgen,4
Andreas,6
Martin,4
```

Comment: @Anto Jurkovic Is google chart supported on mobile devices? does it scale up/down properly?

Comment: I didn't develop for mobile device but most probably it is. Maybe if you check some of examples at [Google Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization).